# How do you get the firebase log viewer to show line numbers?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to get line numbers from log entries, for example when you do a:

`console.log('Already a Thumbnail.');`

It would be nice to see more than:

[image]

Instead it would be useful to also see the line number, particularly as functions get larger, is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Cloud Functions log doesn't have the ability to show line numbers as it's basically reading from `stdout` (or similar).

You may be able to glean further insight by viewing logs through the [Cloud Functions Stackdriver Logging UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/logs?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com) though.

Also, it's worth adding more details to your logs or using tags to distinguish between different `console.log` calls, for example:

```
console.log("ifThumbnailExists: Already a Thumbnail.");
```

And if you want to use the same log message on multiple lines, another line may use:

```
console.log("ifSmallImage: Already a Thumbnail.");
```

Ultimately the idea is that you should be able to tell what line or method the logs are coming from by providing additional details and using unique log messages.